# django request param from urls into views not working

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I m trying to request `table_id` from `table_base.html` and is not returning anything.

This my `table_base.html`

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> {{ table_name }} List</h1>
    {% if list_tables %}
    <table class="table table-bordered sortable">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</a></th>
        <th>Date</a></th>
        <th>Search Button</th>
    </thead>
        {% for list in list_tables %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" >{{ list.id }}</a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'tables:addview' table_id=list.id %}" name="table_name">{{ list.name }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ list.date }}</td>
            <td><a href="#">Search</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
        {% else %}
        <p> No Records Found</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
</div>
```

This is my `tables/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.table_base, name='tables'),
    url(r'^(?P<table_id>\d+)$', views.AboutDetail.as_view(), name='details'),
    url(r'^(?P<table_id>\d+)/details$', views.addview, name='addview')
]
```

This is my `tables/views.py`

```
def table_base(request):
    table_name = Crawledtables._meta.db_table
    list_tables = Crawledtables.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'tables/table_base.html', {'table_name': table_name,
                                                      'list_tables': list_tables})


class AboutDetail(DetailView):
    model = Crawledtables
    pk_url_kwarg = 'table_id'
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AboutDetail, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        if 'table_id' not in self.kwargs:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=1)
        else:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['table_id'])


def addview(request, table_id):
    q = request.GET.get('table_id')
    print q

    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=q)
    print table_name
    AllTables._meta.db_table = table_name.name
    tbl_detail = AllTables.objects.order_by('id')

    return render(request, 'tables/table_list.html', {'details': tbl_detail})
```

It works 1 time. When I select the first table (table with id 1) it gives me all the info. When I try to select another table it gives me this error:

```
InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'table_name.id' in 'field list'")
```

I use print to print me everything. And it shows good response. But in the end it just hits me with error 1054. I can only see 1 table details at a time. If I want to see another table. I have to restart the server.

Comment: Can you post full trace-back ?

Comment: This error clearly has nothing to do with URL kwargs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't run this command

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate
```

your table is not created yet

Comment: my tables are created...and i have done the migrations and it still gives me the same  error

Comment: delete previous migrations file then again try

Comment: thats what i did..cause it didn't let me do migrations..it said the table already exists...so i deleted everything and did the migrations

Comment: i don't know if this helps...but my CrawledTables contains all the table names with the creation date.